# Maven Black-Briar won't talk to me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Maven Black-Briar won't speak to me after Brynjolf has told me to go and speak to her. Do I have to do something else first? Or is there a bug in this quest that I can fix somehow?

Comment: Could you add some more details? Which quest are you on?

Comment: Is this for the quest **Dampened Spirits**? Also, is this PC or console?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The question used to be tagged xbox-360, so either he’s playing on a console, or he just picked a random tag.

Comment: @amaranth That tag should *probably* be restored, so I'm going to do that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, either a tag or having it in the text. I don’t know what the policy on that is.